# Unable to execute Databricks REST API for data copy using Python

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, aws-databricks, databricks-community-edition

When i am executing the below code to "copy data from databricks --> local" its failing with an error.
Can anyone please help me with how to solve this error.

```
import os

from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.dbfs.api import DbfsApi
from databricks_cli.dbfs.dbfs_path import DbfsPath

api_client = ApiClient(host  = r"https://azuredatabricks.net/?o=XXXX",token = "121314141")


dbfs_source_file_path      = 'dbfs:/FileStore/datafilename.csv'
local_file_download_path   = 'C:/world.txt'

dbfs_api  = DbfsApi(api_client)
dbfs_path = DbfsPath(dbfs_source_file_path)

# Download the workspace file locally.
dbfs_api.get_file(dbfs_source_file_path,local_file_download_path,overwrite = True)
```

***Error : Failing for AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'absolute_path'***

*The code is the exact replica of documentation in
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html#download-a-file-from-a-dbfs-path*

Comment: Can you please try using `dbfs_api.get_file(dbfs_path, local_file_download_path,overwrite = True)`

Comment: Tried, same error.

Comment: But this worked ```DbfsApi(api_client).cp(recursive=False, overwrite=True, src=src1, dst=dst1))```

Comment: If your issue is resolved, try posting it as an answer so it helps other community members facing the same issue.

Comment: I think passing `dbfs_source_file_path` is the problem as it is a string. I got the [same error](https://i.imgur.com/i0f8jH3.png) running the code. When I pass `dbfs_path` object instead of string path, then it works fine. This is the [reference image](https://i.imgur.com/JIGgkoU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error when I ran your code. After following the error trace, it can be seen that while using `dbfs_api.get`, the string path is passed instead of the object. Hence the error `'str' object has no attribute 'absolute_path'`.

[image]

- To solve the error, you need to pass the `DbfsPath` object instead of the actual string path. Hence modify your code as following:

```
import os

from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.dbfs.api import DbfsApi
from databricks_cli.dbfs.dbfs_path import DbfsPath

api_client = ApiClient(host  = r"https://azuredatabricks.net/?o=XXXX",token = "121314141")


dbfs_source_file_path      = 'dbfs:/FileStore/datafilename.csv'
local_file_download_path   = 'C:/world.txt'

dbfs_api  = DbfsApi(api_client)
dbfs_path = DbfsPath(dbfs_source_file_path)

# Download the workspace file locally.
dbfs_api.get_file(dbfs_path,local_file_download_path,overwrite = True) #change here
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using below code

```
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient
from databricks_cli.dbfs.api import DbfsApi

api_client = ApiClient(host  = r"https://azuredatabricks.net/?o=XXXX",token = "121314141")

src1 = 'dbfs:/FileStore/datafilename.csv'
dst1 = 'C:/world.txt'

DbfsApi(api_client).cp(recursive=False, overwrite=True, src=src1, dst=dst1))
```

But please, let me know if you could solve the above error